# How to mark non english questions/answers?

Tags: discussion, flagging

Right now I'm reviewing this answer and I don't know what to do:
https://superuser.com/a/792377/180465
(Oh sorry that post is now deleted. Anyway, my question still exists...)

The problem is - it's written in another language (but with english letters) and it's impossible to understand what's written there.
So it can be:

- A real answer, but in another language (I must leave a comment or edit to make it english)
- Spam (add a spam flag)
- Not answer (mark as not-answer)

etc.

So, how to deal with such questions/answers? How to flag these questions?
(P.S. currently I've left a comment for him to write in english and downvoted)

Comment: I usually custom flag it with "not in English".

Comment: I wonder a bit what "english letters" are?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Posts on [Super User must be written in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange). British, American, doesn't matter, so long as it's in English.

If they are spam, then flag as spam.

If they're not spam, then flag as "not an answer" or a custom message pointing out that it isn't written in English.

These posts will be deleted.

If you wanted to translate, that's up to you, but not expected.